# VB Net throws exception after saving to network drive

Tags: vb.net, http, .net-4.0

I am writing a VB.net program which was supposed to access an API and download some data. But I'm having some trouble with even just the basics. I have this simple program:

```
Public Class Form1

  Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
    Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString("http://www.myexternalip.com/raw")

    Debug.WriteLine(result)
  End Sub
End Class
```

As expected, the program runs and prints my external IP -- but *only if i do not save the program!* Once I save the program to our school's network file server, the program stops working:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
```

The program itself is **exactly** the same. Yet all of a sudden, after saving the program to my network folder, it breaks. I have never had this problem before and have been using the network file server for the past 6 months to do VB.net programs.

Not unsurprisingly, if I make a new program (again, not saving) and copy and paste the "broken" code into the new program, it runs fine. Then I save it and it throws an exception.

**My questions:**

- Does this have to do with references? Possibly can the program not find the reference to `System.Net`? However I have never had a problem with references before.
- I am at a high school. Could this have something to do with computer restrictions? Unfortunately there is little information I could provide in this regard. But it seems unlikely that a simple school file server could be causing this behavior.
- Also, does this belong on another stack exchange? Maybe super user?

Thanks.

Comment: When does it throw the exception, at runtime or design time?  Are you executing the program from the network share?  If so, have you [granted trust](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713717(v=vs.110).aspx) on the local machine to the executable?

Comment: The network drive is only a file server. The program (as far as I'm concerned) still runs off of my local computer. The exception happens during execution on the `DownloadString` line (line 2 of the sub).

Comment: What version of .Net are you using?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like you're running into an issue with [Code Access Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/930b76w0%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). By default, .Net Framework versions 2.0 through 3.5 will not *trust* code located on file shares for execution. .Net Framework version 3.5sp1 set this back to something more sane, but it's still something you need to watch for.

What you can do as a quick work-around is to write a batch file that copies the file from the network share to the local system, and then kicks off the copied program. The more robust work-around is to change the code access security settings on the system, typically at the group policy level.